# Tasks executing on own thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, async-await

I have an Action that goes out to three Cosmos DB repositories to retrieve information. The action has the following code:

```
var task1 = _itemRepository.RetrieveByIdAsync(id);
var task2 = _partsRepository.RetrieveForItemAsync(id);
var task3 = _purchasesRepository.RetrieveForItemAsync(id, currentUserId);

var userPurchased = await _userPurchaseRepository.HasUserPurchased(Session.UserId) // this is awaited because it is a SQL task and can only execute one at a time

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
```

What I'm noticing when debugging is that the tasks appear to be running on different threads. `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` is different from before the tasks run, and for each task, and after the tasks are awaited.

> Thread ID before entry - 5
>   Item Repository Thread ID - 61
>   Parts Repository Thread ID - 5
>   Purchases Repository Thread ID - 60
>   Thread ID after WaitAll - 6

The repository methods all eventually call a common QueryAsync method which looks like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TDomainObject>> QueryAsync(Expression<Func<TDomainObject, bool>> predicate, FeedOptions options)
{
    var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<TDomainObject>(Collection.DocumentsLink, options).Where(predicate).AsDocumentQuery();

    List<TDomainObject> results = new List<TDomainObject>();
    while (query.HasMoreResults)
    {
        results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<TDomainObject>());
    }

    return results;
}
```

My understanding is that the same request thread should be used for all processing with async/await, and I'm concerned that my code may not be as performant as it could be.

I'm not using the Thread ID for anything, I just want to make sure I'm not creating unnecessary threads.

**Edit**: What initially made me look into this was I was finding that the call stack in the `QueryAsync` method, when break pointing on results, that the call stack started at the repository and not in the controller.

Comment: ASP.NET dispatcher doesn't have thread affinity.  Continuing on whatever threadpool thread processed the completion notification is a good thing which saves on context switching.

Comment: This should only ever be a problem if you use the Thread ID for something. Wich is a bad idea in the first place. If you need to identify a task, it should be done via a variable given to it/retrieved by it during start. Something like a simple running counter (do not forget the Race condition protection during retrieval/update).

Comment: ASP.NET Core uses/manages a thread pool. When you start a request, it runs on one thread. When you await an async I/O task, the original thread is returned to the thread pool and can be used for other requests until the operation is finished, then it will pick another free/available thread form the thread pool to continue on. It may or may not be the same thread as the original one (cause the original one may already be used by another request or continuation). No new threads are spawned unless you call `Task.Run` or `TaskFactory.StartNew` (bad in web apps in 99% of the cases)

Comment: @Tseng wouldn't it be  recommended to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` explicitly, otherwise continuation would request same thread and may cause a delay

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: Yes, that's the recommended approach for writing reusable libraries. In ASP.NET Core that's not necessary anymore as there's no AspNetSynchronizationContext anymore. In fact the ASP.NET Core dropped the usage of `.ConfigureAwait(false)` in the ASP.NET Core code. But in general purpose libraries (which may be used for Desktop, UI, WPF or Mobile Application) it is still recommended practice to call `.ConigureAwait(false)` on every awaitable task. But in pure ASP.NET Core libraries (one which depends on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` libraries its not necessary anymore

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: Read Stephen Cleary's excellent post on [ASP.NET Core SynchronizationContext](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html) to get more background information on this topic. ASP.NET Core removes some of the pitfalls of the legacy ASP.NET framework. Also `.ConfigureAwait(false)` is only to capture and return to the original context, it won't (iirc) guarantee you to return on the same thread as you started. Switching of context involves some overhead and in UI apps such as WPF can cause deadlocks (hence recommendation of libraries using it)

Comment: The SynchronizationContext then depends on the implementation and platform used. WPF and Asp.NET (the legacy one) have own ones which synchronize it and limit the thread on which its called, console applications and ASP.NET Core just use the default synchronization context and dont have that issues

Comment: @Tseng thanks for the detailed explanation

Comment: @Tseng my understanding is that Task.Run does *not* 'spawn' a new thread, but simple queues the work to be executed via the threadpool.

Comment: @NPSF3000: It uses a thread from a thread pool or spawns one (when there aren't enough in the pool and max limit not exceeded yet). But the code within `Task.Run` runs **synchronous** in a new Thread. So using `Task.Run` in ASP.NET Core to run CPU bound code is pointless. You return one thread to the pool and do the work on the other. You get thread and context switches but no benefit for scaleability. CPU bound work in ASP.NET Core should be done on the request thread. I/O bound work asynch. Parallelism brings no benefits in web apps

Comment: Parallelizing via multiple Task.Runs and awaiting them just will mess up the thread heuristics of ASP.NET Core and lower your overall performance in high traffic scenarios

Comment: @Tseng Source that Task.Run spawns a thread?  I'd like to read more. "So using Task.Run in ASP.NET Core to run CPU bound code is pointless."  I would be hesitant to make such a blanket statement, there may be scenario's beyond those you've considered.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165007/task-spawning-own-thread

Comment: @NPSF3000 Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx), in an example it clearly shows how `Task.Run` request a separate thread from the pool than current application thread. Only use case for `Task.Run` in  Async call would be keeping application responsive by returning the Ui thread, as done in Async button click event, that's also only for thick clients like WPF not for ASP.Net, which is the focus of this question. Javascript anyway makes Async call by default.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj " request a separate thread from the pool than current application thread." Mostly correct, it actually 'Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool'.  This is very different to  Tseng's claim that it 'or spawns one'... which still hasn't been substantiated.  'Only use case' is also unsubstantiated.  Feel free to open a chat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire purpose of the Task Parallel Library and the async/await features is that they abstract away the underlying Threads logic. Unless you are working in a project that works with a framework which has a *Synchronization Context* that runs on the UI Thread (i.e: WinForms, WPF, Xamarin), you should leave the framework determine whether a given `Task` should run on the current thread or on a different one.